# Outlook Add-In Won't Load in Debug Mode

Tags: outlook, add-in, office-addins

I'm coming back to an Outlook Add-In I wrote last year - the Add-In installs and runs just fine (apart from a code issue I'm trying fix) but when I uninstall it (because I must) and try to run the code in Debug mode *it launches Outlook just fine*, but then nothing else - a breakpoint in InternalStartup() never gets hit, nor does one in ThisAddIn_Startup().

The List of Add-ins does not show my Add-in when I'm trying to debug, but it doesn't throw any sort of error or window.  Just... *nothing* happens.  The list of disabled Add-ins doesn't list my Add-in either.

Comment: Does the registry entry for your add-in exist? Is LoadBehavior set to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find the answer on Dan Crevier's Blog post:  [Debugging Outlook Add-ins Doesn't Work if You Have Disabled Add-ins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/31/105084.aspx):

> [...] if you have any disabled Outlook add-ins, VS will not stop at any breakpoints in other add-ins. The fix is to reenable all add-ins.

This kinda hoses me because my Outlook has an Add-in disabled by a corporate policy, but maybe it will help someone else.